# Why is scrapy printing \t\n\n where I expect there to be text?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am a beginner with scrapy, but learning. I have been parsing [this page](https://www.marksandspencer.com/MSStoreDetailsView?storeId=10151&langId=-24&SAPStoreId=6952). 
and am attempting to scrape the address off of the page.

I have done this in the scrapy shell, so I start by:

```
scrapy shell https://www.marksandspencer.com/MSStoreDetailsView?storeId=10151&langId=-24&SAPStoreId=6952
```

Which works fine. Then I attempt to parse the address with:

```
response.xpath('//li[@class="address"]/text()').extract()
```

But my output is the following:

> ['\n\t\t', '\n\t\t\n\t\t']

Why am I not able to see the address as it appears on the page:

> BELFAST ABBEY CENTRE, 1 Old Glenmount Road Newtonabbey, Newton Abbey, BT36 7DN

How would I go about getting this address out?
I appreciate anyone that takes the time to reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple a errors on how you are approaching this issue:

1. When using `scrapy shell`, you have to surround the url with `""`, because the terminal could interpret it as several processes because of the character `&` inside the url:

   ```
   scrapy shell "https://www.marksandspencer.com/MSStoreDetailsView?storeId=10151&langId=-24&SAPStoreId=6952"
   ```
2. Your xpath is not correct because with `/text()` you are getting the text of that particular tag, and that `li` doesn't actually contain the information you want. The tag that includes that text is on the children of that `li` so you could use:

   ```
   response.xpath('//li[@class="address"]//text()').extract()
   ```

   or

   ```
   response.xpath('//li[@class="address"]/p/text()').extract()
   ```